# How to build a relevent benchmark of queries for database systems comparison?

Tags: database, performance, rdf, benchmarking

I plan a comparison study on performances of multiple database systems used in to store and access RDF data through a benchmark of queries. 
I'm thinking about differents kind of database system (native RDF, relational, column-store and so on ...).

My question concerns how to build my benchmark ? In other words. What are the most relevant queries  characteristics in which I must put more emphasis in order to highlight difference between those database, if any ?

Comment: I think this is rather too broad to be asked as a question here. I recommend you have a look at some existing SPARQL/RDF benchmarks (such as LUBM, or the Berlin benchmark) and read some of the related papers on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found [this presentation](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/14302/14302B.pdf) that describe everything one must consider when building a comparative study on database